# how to bind with model with the value from another model in html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you all know *input='date'* will not return the formatted value we want. So I put the pipeline below like *| date: "dd/MM/yyyy"* then I can get what I want. But how can I bind that value with a model?

```
<input ng-disabled="defaultSaveButtons[$index]" ng-init="InitializeDateForToday($index,field)" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control text-right inputFill2" ng-model="deliveryDate" />

<span ng-model="field.value">{{deliveryDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</span>
<br />
<span>{{field.value}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `date` filter inside your controller like below:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.field = { value : "" };
    
    $scope.setField = function() {
      var date = $filter('date')($scope.deliveryDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
      $scope.field.value = date;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ng-model="deliveryDate" ng-change="setField()"/>  
  <br/><br/>
  <span>{{field.value}}</span><br/>
  <span>{{deliveryDate}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is looking good but when I try to filter with date of deliveryDate, I have no value at all. I set *ng-model* and put *ng-change* but *deliverydate* is not bound with value.

Comment: @damnit Are you sure? I added it to the answer, seems to show up

Comment: I tried to send deliveryDate to SetField(deliveryDate), then I can get the data, but when I bind with ng-model="deliveryDate", it's not binding. But thanks to your insight, I can further on!!

Comment: @damnit Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped, and ask more questions if you face any problems. Happy to help :)